# Automatically generate MySQL table after csv file upload

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am working on a PHP/MySQL project, it must verify the following tasks:

-> **The user uploads multiple large CSV files at a time with the same column names (X,Y,Z) in MySQL tables**

-> **The web app must perform an arithmetic operation between each csv file's column**

-> **The user can download the csv files after the operation as Excel files**

For the upload part, i need to find a way to auto generate a table in the database for each csv file uploaded -instead of creating it in advance-, because the user should be able to upload as many files as he wants.

i tried to set a while loop that contains a create table, the loop goes from 0 to $var which is the number of csv files the user wishes to upload, however it doesnt add any table, here's the code for that part :

```
    $con= getdb();

$var=$_GET["quantity"];

mysql_query("set $i=0;
             while $i<`".$var."` do
             create table `couche".$var."` ( X float NOT NULL,Y float NOT NULL,Z float NOT NULL);
             set $i= $i+1;
             end while");
 }
```

Comment: Do you need this data in actual database tables? Or are you just using those as a tool to work with the CSV data, and after the user has downloaded their modified results, those tables would not be needed any more?

Comment: Please read up on best database practices in code. Your code example has all the features to be hacked silly. http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases

Comment: The main objective is to perform an operation on the large csv files, so the database tables would be just a tool , yes.

Comment: Then it might make sense to create temporary tables, or even use the [MEMORY storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-storage-engine.html) - depends on what data volume you have to handle of course.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the following way to achieve it :

```
<?php 

//database connection details
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','db_name') or die('Could not connect to MySQL');

// path where your CSV file is located
define('CSV_PATH','/var/www/html/skerp_scripts/');

// Name of your CSV file
$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "importItems.csv";

if (($handle = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {        
    $header = true;  //If there is a header in first row then set it to true
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if($header == true){
        /* Here you can perform checks whether all the column are as expected 
           for Eg: in CSV1 : id, firstname, lastname, age
            in CSV2 : firstname, age ,id

            Than you can tell the user that there is a misatch
         */
        $header = false;
        continue;
    }
    $column1 = $data[0];
    $column2 = $data[1];
    $column3 = $data[2];

    $calculation = $column1 * $column3;
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3)" VALUES($column1, $column2, $calculation));

    }
}
echo "File data successfully imported to database!!"; 
mysqli_close($connect);
```